# Can I delay jQuery addClass?

Tags: jquery, delay, addclass

Is there a way to delay the `addClass()` of jQuery? For example this code

```
$('#sampleID').delay(2000).fadeOut(500).delay(2000).addClass('aNewClass');
```

When I load the page, it has the class 'aNewClass' already on id 'sampleID'. How to solve this problem? What I want is the addClass will happen after it ended the `fadeOut()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What I want is the addClass will
>   happen **after it ended the fadeOut()**.

You can use [callback function to `fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) like this:

```
$('#sampleID').fadeOut(500, function(){
  $(this).addClass('aNewClass');
});
```

Comment: You haven't replaced the non-functional call to `delay`.

Comment: @lonesomeday: That shouldn't matter in the code but thanks done :)

Answer (score 21):

You can't directly delay an addClass call, however you can if you wrap it in a queue call which takes a function as a parameter like this

```
$(this).delay(2000).queue(function(){$(this).addClass('aNewClass')});
```

See this post: [jQuery: Can I call delay() between addClass() and such?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510115/jquery-can-i-call-delay-between-addclass-and-such)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with `delay` because it only affects the effects queue.  It doesn't "pause" execution of later code if it is not implemented using the queue.

You need to do this with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
$('#sampleID').delay(2000).fadeOut(500, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).addClass('aNewClass');
    }, 2000);
});
```

This uses the `complete` callback of [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and then sets a function to execute 2 seconds in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use setTimeout, with CSS transition :

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#sampleID').addClass('aNewClass');
}, 2000);
```

And the CSS

```
#sampleID {
transition: opacity 1s ease;
opacity: 0;
}

#sampleID.aNewClass {
opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use callbacks .

```
$('#sampleID').delay(2000).fadeOut(500,function(){
   $(this).delay(2000).addClass('aNewClass');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/