# jQuery delay not working

Tags: jquery, delay

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: Can I call delay() between addClass() and such?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510115/jquery-can-i-call-delay-between-addclass-and-such)

Hello I have an issue.

The below jQuery code is not working for me..

```
$("#message").addClass("highlightError").delay(15000).removeClass("highlightError");
```

What's the error?

The class in not even added..I checked with Firebug, no errors  are shown..

Please help

Thanks!|

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510115/jquery-can-i-call-delay-between-addclass-and-such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`removeClass` is not used by the effects queue, so delay has no effect on it.  To cause it to be called in the effects queue, manually add it using [`queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/):

```
$(function(){
    $("#message").addClass("highlightError").delay(2000).queue(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("highlightError");
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
});
```

Works here:  http://jsfiddle.net/QkpJn/1

Answer (score 0):

delay() method allows us to delay the execution of functions that follow it in the queue. It can be used with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue. Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use the effects queue.

Refer to  James Khoury's link to see how you can make custom queues