# SetTimeout is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add and remove a class on click event, it is something like highlight an element, but nothing is happing here :(. Here is my code:
JQ:

```
var listed=($('.vis').size())-1,
btn=$('.compare-btn');
  listed < 5 ? listed>=2?btn.show(500):null):btn.text("more").addClass('border').setTimeout(btn.removeClass('border'),2000);
```

CSS:

```
.border{border:2px solid red;width:95%!important;}
```

please let me know what is wrong with this code

Comment: Check error with using firebug on firefox or another devTools another browsers...

Comment: `setTimeout` is not a method of the jQuery object. It can't be chained to other jQuery methods.

Comment: what is listed and btn.. Can you put html part also ?

Comment: you use setTimeout in the wrong way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setTimeout` is a built in JavaScript method, it's not a part of jQuery, see [the MDN article about it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Refactor

```
btn.text("more").addClass('border').setTimeout(btn.removeClass('border'),2000);
```

To:

```
btn.text("more").addClass('border');
setTimeout(function(){

    btn.removeClass('border');

},2000);
```

I also think that the ternary operator does not help your code very much. It's making it a bit un-readable. Please consider using the simpler `if-else` construct instead, especially if you're not using the return value.

If you'd like, you can use the jQuery [.delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function to accomplish similar syntax to what you attempted [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510115/jquery-can-i-call-delay-between-addclass-and-such). I suggest you keep using `setTimeout` though, it's simpler and native.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is not a jquery function. It needs to be on it's own line:

```
var listed=($('p').size())-1,
    btn=$('.compare-btn');
    if(listed < 5) {
      if(listed>=2) {
         btn.show(500);
      }
      else {
         null;
      }
    }
    else
    {
       btn.text("more").addClass('border');
    }
}

setTimeout(function(){btn.removeClass('border'); } ,2000);
```