# Looping with delay jquery / js

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, traffic, light

I have traffic light - 3 colors:

```
<div class="green" id="ready"></div>
<div class="orange" id="steady"></div>
<div class="red" id="go"></div>
```

and array:

```
var status = ["ready", "steady", "go"];
```

I want add and remove class (to imitate flashing) from each in **infinity** loop with some delay, but this code make it all in one time. How can i solve it?

```
jQuery.each(status, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#" + this).addClass('active');
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: multiply the delay by the index of each iteration.

Comment: bring back the <blink> tag!

Comment: Work with a queue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510115/jquery-can-i-call-delay-between-addclass-and-such

Comment: BTW: green is ready and red is go...?

Answer (score 15):

http://jsfiddle.net/9feh7/

You're setting all to run at once. Multiply by the index each time.

```
$('#ready, #steady, #go').each(function(i) { 
    var el=$(this);
    setTimeout(function() { 
        el.addClass('active');
    }, i * 3000); 
});
```

Note that `i` in the first instace is 0, so if you want #ready to wait 3 seconds use `(i+1) * 3000`

Also, `$('#'+this)` is not correct syntax, it's `$(this)`, however that won't work inside the setTimeout.

Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` to run an infinate (unless cleared) loop.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot - its working now, but with $('#'+status[i]).addClass('active');
Now, how can I run it in infinity loop?

Comment: use setInterval instead of setTimeout : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

Comment: @VojtechLacina, j_mcnally's response is to you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var status = ["ready", "steady", "go"];
var i=1;
jQuery(status).each(function(index,value) {
    var self=this;
    setTimeout(function() {
       $(self).addClass('active');
    }, 3000*i);
    i++;
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/M9NVy/

Comment: Why add another var `i` when you're already creating `index`?

Comment: As index will start from 0 which will add class active without any delay. We can use `index+1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are better off chaining for your end goal.

1) Setup a function for red. at the end of the red function schedule yellow with a set timeout 1000 ms.
2) At the end of yellow schedule 1000ms time out for red

3) At the end of green schedule 1000ms timeout for green.

4) start your code by calling red()

Now it will loop infinitely with out the awkwardness of multiplying your timeout.

If you hate that then I would use setInterval rather than setTimeOut but you may need more math.