# Changing the class of a div after a time delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class

I am wanting add a class to a div element (id="one") 10 seconds after a page loads, without anything having to be hovered on or clicked on etc. I tried the following code but it does not work:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


$(document).ready(function(){
$('#one').delay(10000).addClass("grow")
});
```

Any idea where the above code is going wrong?

Comment: [`.delay()` is not a replacement for JavaScript's native `setTimeout` function](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: `.delay()` only works in the context of jQuery animations. Just use `setTimeout()`.

Comment: `$('#one').delay(10000).queue(function(){$(this).addClass("grow");})` http://jsfiddle.net/9k4vw/ or use a timeout

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Can I call delay() between addClass() and such?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510115/jquery-can-i-call-delay-between-addclass-and-such)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `delay` method adds an item to the animation queue, but as `addClass` is not an animation effect, it's not put on the queue, it takes effect right away.

You can use the `queue` method to put code in the animation queue, so that it runs after the delay:

```
$('#one').delay(10000).queue(function(){
  $(this).addClass("one");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6V9rX/

An alternative to use animation for the delay is to use the `setTimeout` method:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
  $('#one').addClass("one");
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 4):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/6kTgC/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $("#one").addClass("one");
    },10000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`delay` [only works on elements on jQuery's queue](http://api.jquery.com/delay/). Since addClass isn't <strike>an animation</strike> added to the queue by default, it runs immediately regardless of `delay`. You should use Javascript's native `setTimeout` for general delays:

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#one').addClass("grow")
    }, 10000);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4HShh/1/)