# Applying delay to animation jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class to a div in my `html` but would like to add a delay before doing so. 
I've got the following code below but it does not seem to be applying any sort of delay. Can anyone advise me of what I am doing wrong?

```js
$("#globe").on('ended',function() {
  setTimeout(
    $('.faculty-info').addClass('cbp-spmenu-open'), 
    5000);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Can I call delay() between addClass() and such?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510115/jquery-can-i-call-delay-between-addclass-and-such)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` requires a function definition as first parameter, so wrap whatever you want to do in an anonymous function like bellow

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.faculty-info').addClass('cbp-spmenu-open')
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoudl wrap your code (instructions to be performed in a delay fashion) in a `function`.

```js
$("#globe").on('ended',function() {
  setTimeout( function() {
    $('.faculty-info').addClass('cbp-spmenu-open')
  }, 5000);
});
```

You may also need to declare a variable to hold the timeout value. This will give you the possibility to clear it once you are in need:

```js
//Global timeout variable
var timeOut;

$("#globe").on('ended',function() {
  timeOut = setTimeout( function() {
    $('.faculty-info').addClass('cbp-spmenu-open')
  }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) to handle this:

```
$("#globe").on('ended', function () {
    $('.faculty-info').delay(5000).queue(function () {
        $(this).addClass('cbp-spmenu-open').dequeue();
    });
});
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbuckley/u16dh890/). See also: [jQuery: Can I call delay() between addClass() and such?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510115/jquery-can-i-call-delay-between-addclass-and-such)