# How do I add time delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to add a custom class on mouseover. So that when the mouse is hovered over `.leftbar`, a class is added and it should be popped up(I set css for his). How do I add `slow` or time delay for the popup?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".leftbar" ).mouseenter(function() {
$( "body" ).addClass( "myclass" );
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".leftbar" ).mouseleave(function() {
$( "body" ).removeClass( "myclass1" );
});
});
</script>
```

I tried this- `$( "body" ).addClass( "myclass" , '300');` with no luck

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510115/jquery-can-i-call-delay-between-addclass-and-such

Comment: queue is your friend: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.queue/

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".leftbar" ).mouseenter(function() {
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $( "body" ).addClass( "myclass" );
        }, 300);
    });
}):
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Use a `setTimeout`, being sure to clear it when the cursor leaves.

Minor error, but `myclass != myclass1`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var barTimeout = 0;
    $( ".leftbar" ).on({
        mouseenter: function(){
            barTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                $( "body" ).addClass( "myclass" );
            }, 300);
        },
        mouseleave: function(){
            if( typeof barTimeout !== 'undefined' ) clearTimeout( barTimeout );
            $( "body" ).removeClass( "myclass" );
        }
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jgjggLng/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works. I am failing to add easing effect to this code - http://jsfiddle.net/3ts4tb8a/. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the jQuery UI method `addClass` which allows you to pass in some animation parameters into it. View the example and documentation here http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/

For your use, it should be as simple as adding in the delay to `addClass()`

Add a reference to the jQuery Library, then change your code to;

```
$("body").addClass("myclass", 300);
```

Comment: Did you add the reference the jQueryUI?

Comment: yes, please take a look at the pastebin code- http://pastebin.com/7qr8yh27. I tried an easing effect.

Comment: in your example you have `removeClass` on both enter and leave?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".leftbar").hover( function () {
        $(this).delay(300).queue(function(next){
            $(this).addClass("myclass");
            next();
        });
    }, function(){
        $(this).delay(300).queue(function(next){
            $(this).removeClass("myclass");
            next();   
        });
    });
});
```

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k20zbtny/3/)

Comment: Can you help adding an easing effect? This is what I tried - http://jsfiddle.net/3ts4tb8a/ .