# jQuery: Delay between addclass()

Tags: jquery

I've got the problem, that I tried to set my delay like the following post:
[stackoverflow: jQuery: Can I call delay() between addClass() and such?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510115/jquery-can-i-call-delay-between-addclass-and-such)
But it doesnt work for me.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usascj4o/12/)

```
$( "#nav2" ).click(function() {
    var notshown = $("#dropdown1", "#dropdown2");
    var dropdown2 = $("#dropdown2");
    if (dropdown2.hasClass( "unselected" ) || dropdown2.hasClass( "unshown" ) ) {
        notshown.removeClass('unshown').delay(1000).queue(function(){
            var dropdown1 = $("#dropdown1");
            var dropdown2 = $("#dropdown2");
            var navwrapper = $("#navwrapper");
            dropdown1.removeClass('unselected');
            dropdown2.removeClass('unselected');
            navwrapper.removeClass('unselected');
            dropdown1.addClass('unselected').dequeue();
            };

    }else{
        dropdown2.addClass('unshown');
        navwrapper.addClass('unselected');
        dropdown1.addClass('unshown');
    }
});
```

Also tried with fadeIn/Out, but still no movement.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usascj4o/9/)

```
$("#nav1").click(function () {
    var dropdown1 = $("#dropdown1");
    var dropdown2 = $("#dropdown2");
    var navwrapper = $("#navwrapper");
    if (dropdown1.hasClass("unshown")) {
        dropdown1.removeclass('unshown');
        dropdown1.delay(200).fadeIn(500).delay(200);
        navwrapper.removeclass('unshown');
    } else {
        dropdown2.addclass('unshown');
        navwrapper.addclass('unshown');
        dropdown1.delay(200).fadeOut(500);
        dropdown1.addclass('unshown');
    };
};
```

Comment: `"It doesn't work for me"` How?

Comment: @Newd I want to remove the unshown class and after that I want a delay to addclass and removeclass the unselected, so it isnt a "popup", when you change the display in css. 
If I just change the display mode, it can't be faded in with css.
And if i just make it with the rgba it's still clickable.

Comment: @Chimposant: the `#nav1` clicks work fine right? It is the `#nav2` clicks that are creating problems for you?

Comment: @TahirAhmed [link](http://jsfiddle.net/usascj4o/9/) that's the latest version that was working. But the problem is still, if i use "display:none", the links are "popped" out, so there is no fadeIn/fadeOut when the navwrapper is contracting or expanding.

Comment: @Chimposant: so if I understand it correctly, you want the `navwrapper` to contract first, before expanding again. You want to transition from one another but with the `navwrapper` expanding and contracting in between?

Comment: @Chimposant: Oh hang on! your fadeIn and Outs are the ones not working that you want to fix. I think I get it now.

Comment: @TahirAhmed The `navwrapper` should expand first, but stay expanded, if I click on the second link and the links in `#nav2` and `#nav1` should fadeout and dissappear, when the `navwrapper` contracts

Comment: @Chimposant: Have you considered using `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` instead of `display: none;` rule in your `.unshown` selectors?

Comment: @TahirAhmend That's what I tried in the 2nd code. But can't get it working.

Comment: @Chimposant: Ok. Hang in there.

Comment: @Chimposant: Take a look at **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/usascj4o/13/)** and tell me if this is what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you very very very much. That's perfect. I'm so glad that a site and guys like you exist! :)
Post an answer to let me approve it.

Comment: @Chimposant: Glad it helped. Let me post an answer and I'll try to explain what has changed and what could / should have been done.

Comment: @Chimposant: I have to say though, currently it has become a mixture of CSS `transition` (for `#navwrapper` element) and jQuery's `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` (for `#dropdown1` and `#dropdown2` elements). And IMHO, this shouldn't be the case. Do you want me to try out even the `#navwrapper` animations with jQuery so that you will know that all the animations are done using jQuery alone?

Comment: @TahirAhmed I'm open for any advices and help. Feel free to do so! :)

Comment: @Chimposant: Mind if I ask, why were you transitioning the `a` inside the dropdown elements i.e. changing colour but with a transition? It is not very much visible anyway right?

Comment: @TahirAhmed forwarding for the stylesheet, its not finished. Want hover effects etc.

Or did you mean why i want the transition when I click? It's just eyecandy

Comment: @Chimposant: for now, I have pasted the same answer that resolved your immediate query and was in fact a quick fix. I will try to find some time tomorrow to really resolve it for good. Hopefully :) have fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right.

So if I understood it correctly, your solution required *animating* the `display: none;` on the dropdown elements but it could've been resolved by simply using jQuery's `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` methods.

Here is the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usascj4o/14/)** of which, JavaScript of which is as follows:

```
var dropdown1 = $('#dropdown1');
var dropdown2 = $('#dropdown2');
var navwrapper = $('#navwrapper');
var allDropdowns = $('#dropdown1, #dropdown2');
$('#nav1').click(function () {
    if (dropdown1.hasClass('unselected')) {
        allDropdowns.removeClass('unselected');
        navwrapper.removeClass('unselected');
        dropdown2.addClass('unselected');
        dropdown1.fadeIn();
    } else {
        allDropdowns.fadeOut();
        dropdown1.addClass('unselected');
        navwrapper.addClass('unselected');
    }
});
$('#nav2').click(function () {
    if (dropdown2.hasClass('unselected')) {
        allDropdowns.removeClass('unselected');
        navwrapper.removeClass('unselected');
        dropdown1.addClass('unselected');
        dropdown2.fadeIn();
    } else {
        allDropdowns.fadeOut();
        dropdown2.addClass('unselected');
        navwrapper.addClass('unselected');
    }
});
```

***Update:***

Here is an **[updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/usascj4o/15/)** of the same using all but jQuery for animations, snippet below:

```js
var nav1 = $('#nav1');
var nav2 = $('#nav2');
var dropdown1 = $('#dropdown1');
var dropdown2 = $('#dropdown2');
var navwrapper = $('#navwrapper');
var allDropdowns = $('#dropdown1, #dropdown2');
var duration = 300;
allDropdowns.hide();
navwrapper.hide();
nav1.click(function () { toggleFade(dropdown1); });
nav2.click(function () { toggleFade(dropdown2); });
function toggleFade(dropdown) {
    if (!dropdown.is(':visible')) {
        allDropdowns.fadeOut(duration);
        navwrapper.slideDown(duration);
        dropdown.fadeIn(duration);
    } else {
        allDropdowns.fadeOut(duration);
        navwrapper.slideUp(duration);
    }
}
```

```css
a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navwrapper {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
}
#dropdown1, #dropdown2 {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    position: absolute;
}
#dropdown1 a, #dropdown2 a { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="nav1">YouTube</a>
<a href="#" id="nav2">Twitch</a>
<div id="navwrapper">
  <span id="dropdown1">
    <a href="#">Sodapoppin</a> <a href="#">Gronkh</a> <a href="#">Deine Mama</a>
  </span>
  <span id="dropdown2">
    <a href="#">Deine Mama</a> <a href="#">Gronkh</a> <a href="#">Sodapoppin</a>
  </span>
</div>
```