# why can't I delay addClass and removeClass using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
   $("#form_editor").addClass('abcd')
   $("#form_editor").delay(32000).removeClass('abcd')
```

The class never gets applied if I have the second line **uncommented**. If I comment it out, then the class gets applied as expected. It seems that the second line executes without any delay at all i.e. ignores `.delay(32000)`.

Does delay work with `addClass` and `removeClass`? I assumed it would delay the call to any function that came after it, but apparently not as it seems to execute right away.

Comment: You have to queue it. Why not just use a good ol' fashioned setTimeout()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Can I call delay() between addClass() and such?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510115/jquery-can-i-call-delay-between-addclass-and-such)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can, but you need to [`queue()`](https://api.jquery.com/queue/)

```js
$("#form_editor").addClass('abcd').delay(3200).queue(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('abcd');
});
```

```css
.abcd:before{
  content:"abcd";
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form_editor">efgh....</div>
```

#### or use `setTimeout` method:

```js
var $formEditor = $("#form_editor"); // we plan to reuse it so let's cache it!

$formEditor.addClass('abcd'); // add

setTimeout(function(){
  $formEditor.removeClass('abcd');  // remove
}, 3200);
```

```css
.abcd:before{
  content:"abcd";
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form_editor">efgh....</div>
```

jQuery animations (.animate, .fadeTo, fadeIn, etc...) add to the animation queue stack, an jQuery internal function than handles *"what's next?"* (laically speaking), while other *"animation-less"* methods (like .text(), addClass(), .on(), .click() etc...) do not.

To easily remember `.queue()` think of it as the missing (really is) callback functionality for `.delay(2000, function(){ /*BAM!*/ }) /* well sadly, this does not works */`

Comment: perfect just what I needed, thanks for this example :)

Comment: @lazy_coder (thx but) please have patience - OP needs to wait 10 minutes before being able to accept answers.

Comment: done, I tried to accept right away but had to wait as mentioned and I forgot about it :)