# How to add delay to jQuery .addClass and .removeClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a **delay** to .addClass and .removeClass for `200ms` here:

```
jQuery('.class').hover(() => jQuery('#custom').addClass('addedclass'), () => jQuery('#custom').removeClass('addedclass'));
```

I tried this example [jQuery: Can I call delay() between addClass() and such?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510115/jquery-can-i-call-delay-between-addclass-and-such) but the structure there is slightly different.

Comment: At which point to you want the delay to occur? `hover`'s first argument occurs when the mouse cursor enters the element, and the second argument is called when the mouse cursor leaves the element. Adding a delay between them doesn't make a lot of sense. If you want to delay the removal of the class after the the mouse has left the element, one of the answers to the linked post should work fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27623259/215552

Comment: I needed to shortly delay the class addition on hover and also delay it when mouse it not hovering it. To lose the instant appearance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to achieve it.

```js
jQuery('.class').hover(
() => setTimeout(() => jQuery('#custom').addClass('addedclass'), 200), 

() => setTimeout(() => jQuery('#custom').removeClass('addedclass'), 200));
```

```css
.addedclass{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="class">
  <p id="custom">Text</p>
</div>
```